# AWS API Gateway requests with federated identity IAM authorisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API that I need to call from my react-native fetch method after v4 signing. The API uses lambda proxy as functions.
My API is set to IAM authentication.
The client side app has username/passwd, fb login and exchanges tokens with identity pool to assume a role that has permission to execute-api, etc.
However, when I test API access using POSTMAN and credentials obtained by a loggedin user with valid tokens after exchanging with the federated identity provider, the result is "the token is invalid".
Please inform what am I missing here. 
PS The javascript SDK generated for the API does not work in react-native's environment and needs changes.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you provided enough information to identify the issue. I guess there may be couple possible case. 1. You might not have the session token in the request via POSTMAN, 2. You might have a wrong URL to API Gateway. Can you provide the raw request from POSTMAN with masked credentials and API id?

Comment: Any luck here? I'm working on the same problem.

Comment: Yes, KaHou kindly helped me solve the problem earlier.
You must include the session token when API gateway is set to IAM auth.
X-Amz-Security-Token
My own question in was forums and discussed with @KaHouIeong
[link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=774699#774699)
Hope this helps.